# What keyword should I research? Designing complicated bulk data uploader

Tags: upload

I am designing a bulk data upload page for some fintech app.

Outside a normal uploading process, I was asked to put files and investors' name side by side so user can link uploaded files to investors.

My first instinct is to use tags, but my boss doesn't like that idea because each time user would upload hundreds of files. I am out of idea and honestly haven't seen anything similar. Do you guys have any idea where should I start? What kind of keywords should I use to find me something similar with that?

This is what my boss wants that is clearly not user friendly.
[image]

This is what I come up with for now.
[image]
I am wondering if there's a better solution.

Comment: Can you provide a mock-up of what you **were** going to do? It may help clarify your question a little. Also, is there a defined number of investors, or could there be hundreds of those as well?

Answer (score 1):

There are two actions here which you need to consider.

1. Uploading the files
2. Associating the files with the user who has uploaded them

My suggestion would be to use a process which allows the user to upload the files and then add a name mapping to it so that all the files uploaded in that session are associated with the name mapping

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fON1kB.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The mockup above uses a two step process where you first upload the files and then map a name to it in bulk

Comment: This is what I would do if all the uploaded files can be associate to the same name. So the thing is before that pops up, the system will try to automatically match based on file names first, and then user needs to manually add names to the rest of files. That's the part I need to figure out. I'm gonna add a screenshot to the main question to explain it better.